# Wifi switch wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, smart-switch

We are trying to replace three old 3-way switches with new wifi 3 way switches. Everything went smoothly until maybe a few minutes after powering back on, the main breaker tripped. We wired everything to the best of out knowledge and instructions but no matter what it still keeps tripping the main breaker.

The one that is installed in the image works fine (it's standard not 3 way) and doesn't trip the circuit (it's the other three slots that are causing trouble).

The last slot on the right was a bit tricky to figure out as it has one black, one red and one white wire. The red and the white wires are hot when checked with a meter. The black isn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Oh and also to note. The first slot on the left has 2 black and 1 red line with 1 black being hot, the third slot from the left has 2 black and 1 red with 1 black and 1 red being hot. The questionable wiring would be (starting from the left going right) slots 1, 3, and 4. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Some formatting will make this wall of text easier to read.

Comment: 1 - (Most important) **Make & Model # of the new switches**, 2 - Picture of junction boxes showing wiring of the other switches (a 3-way means there is another 3-way someplace else)

Comment: When you say "checked with a meter", do you mean: 1 - Non-contact tester lights up or 2 - Multimeter shows voltage between this wire and ground/box/?

Comment: It appears no wires at all (except safety ground) cross over from the left side to the right side of the box.  *You'll need to keep it that way*.  If you were adding wires that cross over from left to right group, that may explain your trips. Does the breaker  have a TEST button?   3-way circuits are complicated enough; smart switches make it a lot more complicated.

Comment: How were the old switched wired?

Comment: Picture of breaker panel and list of your test equipment.